# What script/user/process is writing to a file?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to find out what script/user/process is writing to a file .
I have 4 hosts that have the same NFS mounted 
I have made a scipt and put it on all of the host and with no success 
Can sombody please help with this
The script is running from 5:50 to 6:10 this is the period when the my file gets written to
This is the script that I made :

```
#!/bin/sh
log=~/file-access.log

check_time_to_run() {
  tempTime=$1
  if [ $tempTime -gt 555 -a $tempTime -lt 610 ]; then 
    #Intre intervalul 5:55 si 6:10
    lsof /cdpool/Xprint/Liste_Drucker >> $log
  else
    #In afara intervalului
    exit 1
  fi
}

while true; do
  currTime=`date +%k%M`
  check_time_to_run $currTime
  sleep 0.1s
done
```

Comment: A polling approach is much less likely to be effective for this than would, say, sysdig (http://www.sysdig.org/) -- which records every syscall run on the entire machine, rather than just checking periodically who has a given file open. Every 10th of a second might as well be an eternity.

Comment: If you were on OS X, Solaris or FreeBSD, I'd be telling you to use dtrace for the same purpose, and for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a shell script for this at all. Instead, install [sysdig](http://www.sysdig.org/), and run:

```
sysdig 'fd.filename=/cdpool/Xprint/Liste_Drucker'
```

...leave that open, and whenever anything writes to or reads from that file, an appropriate log message will be printed.

---

If you want to print both the username and the process name (with arguments) for the job printing to the file, the following format string will do so:

```
sysdig \
  -p '%user.name %proc.name - %evt.dir %evt.type %evt.args' \
  'fd.filename=/cdpool/Xprint/Liste_Drucker'
```

Comment: Nice and usefull tool sysdig , will use it in the futere :) But it does not tell me who wrote to the file that i'm monitoring , is there a option to add to show this too ?

Comment: Actually -- by default, it **does** show the process name. The default format string is `%evt.num %evt.time %evt.cpu %proc.name (%thread.tid) %evt.dir %evt.type %evt.args` -- thus including `%proc.name`, the process name.

Comment: If you want the username, then provide a custom format string including `%user.name`.

Comment: By the way, if you want an example of manipulating logs from sysdig using bash, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sysdig/eSKv_CLnpUE/DZeT7H9SbWgJ (the particular example prints execve call arguments in an eval-safe form).